# Problem with custom jQuery.validator rule

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with this code that I can't seem to figure out:

```
$.validator.addMethod('street_address', function (value, element) {
  var address  = value + ', ' + $(element).parent().parent().find("#venue_city_id option:selected").text(),
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
      that     = this;
  geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (results, status) {
    return that.optional(element) || status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK;
  });
}, 'invalid address');
```

It works to invalidate an incorrect address (one that is not geocodeable by Google). The problem is even when it returns true, I'm still getting 'invalid address'. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return from inside callback in

```
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (results, status) {
    return that.optional(element) || status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK;
});
```

Not from validator function.

Moreover, `geocoder.geocode` performs, I believe, asynchronous ajax query, so you'll not be able to tell whether your location is "geocodeable" when leaving you validator. There should be a specific validator for such cases in jQuery validation, called `remote` or something, which validates basing on the result of ajax query.

Comment: Yes, it seems it has to do with the fact that `geocoder.geocode` is an async request. The `remote` validation doesn't seem to be what I need, though.

Comment: The reason for why the code does not work is 100% clear, not just "seems": you do not return from the validator function. You define another function inline and return from it, but it has influence on how the validator works. The fix is not easy, as `geocoder.geocode` is async, but the fix was not a question.

Comment: it has NO influence I meant to say